# TFS 2010 Build 2 projects in Solution not transforming web.configs

Tags: asp.net, transform, tfsbuild

I have two web applications in a solution which is build using TFS.
The main web application's web.configs are correctly transformed depending on the configuration setting of the build.

In the second web application the project is build and deployed but the web.config is not transformed and all transform web.configs are copied to the publish location.
I.e.:
web.config, 
web.dev.config, 
web.testing.config

In the build settings > Process > Items to build I have added the solution file. The build says "There are 1 projects for 1 platform and configuration" I am not sure if this is correct. Should it not see both my web applications?

How do I set-up the TFS build to transform both projects web.configs?

Answer (score 1):

Which version of TFS are you using? Have a look here anyway as it might answer you: http://nirajrules.wordpress.com/2011/07/04/integrating-web-config-transformations-with-tfs-build/

Comment: I think you have to add some parameters in the build definition and in your projects. I used this link to setup transformations long time ago.

Comment: Here is another topic on it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867107/trigger-config-transformation-in-tfs-2010-or-msbuild

Comment: I have added the TransformXml task to the AfterBuild target in my project file. The transformation now works but the transform configs are still not deleted.

Comment: Hi skyfoot, now that your transformation is working outside the build, you can add this to your msbuild parameters: /p:TransformWebConfigEnabled=false.

Comment: That doesn't work. My other web application is fine, the we.config transforms and the transform configs are deleted leaving only web.config. This is not the case for my this web application in the same solution.