# Does Application_Start execute before Web.config file transformation?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio

I have a transformation file that adds a key to the `appconfig` section of `Web.config`. Then in the `Application_Start` method I'm trying to read that added key, but it doesn't seem to be there.  When I do a 'preview transform' on the transformation file, the preview looks OK, with the line added.

**Question:** Does `Application_Start` run before the `Web.config` is transformed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The transformation happens only during actual deployment and **not** during the build process. In your case, it might not be happening at all.

It is possible to trigger the transformation during build, although it requires modifying the project file manually to make it happen. [This post](http://www.damirscorner.com/TransformationOfConfigurationFilesInBuildProcess.aspx) offers some insight on how to do it.

However, you could use `MSBuild` from the command line to perform the transformation (look [in here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2010trainingcourse_webdevelopment_topic4.aspx)), so you might be able to trigger a post-build event to do it. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4960852/1250033) might offer exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1):

As @rae1n explained in his answer, web.config is transformed during the deployment, eg. when you decide to publish a release version of your web application. The `Application_Start` is the entry point of your web application, that is, the first thing being executed when your application is up and running. Think about `Application_Start` as `Main` method in C# console application. Your application is compiled and any transformations needed were completed. You deployed your application and an end user started it. I hope this is now a bit clear for you.