# Process tokens in TfvcRelease12 build template 2013.4

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, release-management, ms-release-management

How do I process tokens in the TfvcRelease 12 build template for TFS and Release Management 2013.4? I have both web.config and web.config.tokens files. I've seen this way:

http://www.colinsalmcorner.com/post/webdeploy-and-release-management--the-proper-way

But it also looks like this can be a solution:

```
/p:UseWPP_CopyWebApplication=true /p:PipelineDependsOnBuild=false
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn the "Process tokens" flag to **true** in the release section of the build process template and make sure the `web.config.token` file is set to "Copy Always" in the application's project file.

Another option that I've had some success with is to define a web.config transform for, say, the Release build configuration. In the transform, replace the baseline values in the web.config with the tokens. Then, open up the project file and add this snippet:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <TransformXml Condition="Exists('$(OutDir)\_PublishedWebsites\$(TargetName)')"
                  Source="Web.config"
                  Transform="$(ProjectConfigTransformFileName)"
                  Destination="$(OutDir)\_PublishedWebsites\$(TargetName)\Web.config" />
</Target>
```

[[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5255164/781754)]

That snippet will force the config transform to run, but only if it's building on a TFS build server. It works wonderfully.

Note: All this will do is copy the `web.config.token` file over the `web.config` file during the build process. It's up to you to then define the tokens within your component in RM, and then provide values in your release template.

Comment: Turning on "process tokens" worked perfectly! Is it usually recommended to set both web.config and web.config.token to "do not copy" in the "copy output to folder" property?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to have the overhead of maintaining a web.config.token file? You don't need the token file if you use the transform technique - much cleaner.

Comment: @GrahamSmith Agreed. I answered the question as stated, then provided the config transform approach as an alternative. I have no strong preference. The token file approach is good in that it applies universally -- you can do it with app.configs. Web.config transforms are just that: **web**.config transforms.

Comment: @DanielMann Profuse apologies - I meant that question for m00nbeam360. Agreed that it does mean treating app.configs differently. I know it's not been updated recently but I have looking at SlowCheetah on my to-do list.

Answer (score 3):

Both are valid but I prefer /p:UseWPP_CopyWebApplication=true /p:PipelineDependsOnBuild=false since it's cleaner. I have a blog post [here](http://pleasereleaseme.net/continuous-delivery-tfs-preparing-deployment-pipeline/) that gives the details of how to set this up. Another of [my posts](http://pleasereleaseme.net/continuous-delivery-tfs-building-deployment-pipeline-using-agent-based-release-template/) explains the process of actually replacing the tokens with values for the environment being deployed to in an agent-based scenario. I'll have a PowerShell version of this available sometime this week as part of my [Continuous Delivery with VSO](http://pleasereleaseme.net/continuous-delivery-with-vso/) series.